# Getting RESTful web services on my odd Tomcat server?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

My Tomcat server isn't 100% like others and I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2009/02/rest-jersey-configuration-on-tomcat.html

So far I have downloaded:

```
asm-3.3.1.jar
jersey-client-1.17.jar
jersey-core-1.17.jar
jersey-server-1.17.jar
```

And put them in my /lib/ directory.

My folder structure is like this:

```
/WEB-INF/classes/rest/com/mkyong/HellowWorldService.class
```

I have my web.xml defined as:

```
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlets/servlet/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm not sure the URL pattern is right?

When I visit `myserver.com/servlets/servlet/rest/hello/Eric` I should get it to say Jersey say: Eric but instead I get a HTTP Status 500 error:

http://pastebin.com/iq5NDVw4

Tomcat log is saying:

```
Feb 19, 2013 4:46:21 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.mkyong.rest
Feb 19, 2013 4:46:21 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17 01/17/2013 04:27 PM'
Feb 19, 2013 4:46:21 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
Feb 19, 2013 4:46:27 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
```

Any help greatly received!

Edit:

I found [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-the-resourceconfig-instance-does-not-contain-any-root-resource-classes/) on the guys page. But it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: tried to add all .jars like jersey-servlet-1.17.jar?

Comment: I didn't see one on the Jersey page called that. Thought maybe they don't use it anymore?

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html

Comment: I've always used the http://maven.java.net/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=com.sun.jersey&a=jersey-archive&v=1.17&e=zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

corresponding to this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html#installation,

> This name is derived from the "display-name" defined in the web.xml
>   file, augmented with the servlet-mapping url-pattern and the "hello"
>   @Path annotation from your class file.

according to this, in your case the `display-name` in your `web.xml` has `" "` and is not mentioned in the link you use for testing.

Edit: 
The base URL of this servlet is:

```
http://your_domain:port/display-name/url-pattern/path_from_rest_class
```

Comment: I have it set as <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>, so where abouts should I put that in the URL?

Comment: myserver.com/Restful Web Application/servlets/servlet/rest/hello/Eric

Comment: remove those " " in display-name

Answer (score 0):

Look at tomcat log. Maybe you should put some jar libraries at /WEB-INF/lib or /tomcat/lib directory. Maybe some libraries using at runtime. Read tomcat logs attentive.